# How do I change the contrast of a picture using Wand?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, wand

I have the picture below used in Tesseract OCR:

[image]

My code to process the picture is:

```
# HOCR
with image[450:6200, 840:3550] as cropped:
    imgPage = wi(image = cropped)
    imageBlob = imgPage.make_blob('png')
    horas = gerarHocr(imageBlob)

def gerarHocr(imageBlob):
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imageBlob))
    markup = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(image, lang='por', extension='hocr', config='--psm 6')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, features='html.parser')

    spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'ocrx_word'})

    listHoras = []
    ...
    return listHoras
```

Although my OCR is getting sometimes confused and duplicating `8` with `3` and returning `07:44/14:183` instead of `07:44/14:13` for example.

I think if I remove the grey lines using Wand I improve the confidence of the OCR.
How do I do that, please?

Thank you,

Comment: Use the [Image.level](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.8/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.level) method.

Comment: maybe get it as numpy array and use something like `img[ img > 128 ] = 255
` to convert some gray colors to white colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the system is using ImageMagick-6, you can call [`Image.threshold()`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.8/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.threshold), but might need to remove the transparency first.

```py
with Image(filename='PWILE.png') as img:
    img.background_color = 'WHITE'
    img.alpha_channel = False
    img.threshold(threshold=0.5)
    img.save(filename='output_threshold.png')
```

[image: Image.threshold]

If you're using ImageMagick-7 (anything above version `7.0.8-41`), then [`Image.auto_threshold()`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.8/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.auto_threshold) will work.

```py
with Image(filename='support/PWILE.png') as img:
    img.auto_threshold(method='otsu')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `cv2` and/or `numpy.array`

to convert light gray colors to white

```
img[ img > 128 ] = 255
```

to convert dark gray colors to black

```
img[ img < 128 ] = 0
```

---

```
import cv2

folder = '/home/user/images/'

# read it
img = cv2.imread(folder + 'old_img.png')

# convert ot grayscale
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# reduce colors

img[ img > 128 ] = 255
img[ img < 128 ] = 0

# save it    
cv2.imwrite(folder + 'new_img.png', img)

# display result
#cv2.imshow('window', img)
#cv2.waitKey(0) # press any key in window to close it
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result

[image]